# Variable Variables in PHP email

Tags: php, css, email, variables

So normally I use a stylesheet and classes (truck1, truck2, truck3...) to handle applying colors to rows in a table, but unfortunately, email does not allow me to use a style sheet or declare styles in the head, so I need to do it inline.

I run a loop that returns appointments, and each appointment has a route/truck number (i.e. truck1, truck2, truck3).  So, in order to declare different colors for each route, I have to use variable variables.

```
$truck0 = "#ffffff";
$truck1 = "#ffcccc";
$truck2 = "#ffffcc";
$truck3 = "#ccffcc";
$truck4 = "#ccffff";
$truck5 = "#ccccff";

while ($rowES1 = $resultES1->fetch_assoc()) { 
    $route = $rowES1["routes"];
    $message .= '<tr style = "background-color: '.$$route.';">'
}
```

Unfortunately, background-color appears blank once this is processed.  Am I doing this wrong?  Is there an easier way to do this inline?

edit: I am sure that $rowES1["routes"] returns either "truck1", "truck2", "truck3", "truck4", or "truck5" because I use it elsewhere.

Comment: remove one $ from $route in $message

Comment: Why bother with `$$route`? It would be simpler and safer to use `$routes = array('truck0' => '#ffffff' ...)` and then `$routes[$route]`.

Comment: @xlordt It seems that `$$route` is intentional: it gets the appropriate color from among the variables listed.

Comment: Yes, thanks I just realized that when reading your post.

Comment: @waleedkhan still, I think your solution is more elecant than mine, so I can try it that way, thanks!  If you add it as an answer, I can mark it correct once the post has been up 10 mins.

Comment: Do you mean that the background color text in the source is literally blank, or that it doesn't render? For one thing, you're nesting `tr`s and that might cause the color not to render.

Comment: @waleedkhan it returns as: <tr style = "background-color: ;">

Comment: The sugestion by @WaleedKhan is what you want to go with.  This would be must better coding practice to have all these related settings in a single array that maps the route to the colors to be used.  This is also much more scalable if you need to add new routes.  What if you have 100 routes, do you want 100 different variables?

Comment: @mike i agree, i actually have 37 routes, so certainly better the was waleedkhan did it

Comment: Why is it that your array has `routes` as a key, but it corresponds to a single route? If `routes` is somehow not a single route, but an array or a delimiter-separated string, this approach would fail.

Comment: @waleedkhan I'm not actually sure what you are asking, I think the problem is that I was trying to do it without an array, and I wanted my variable name to change based on the row information.